# Concatenating multiple pandas dataframes when columns are not aligned

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 dataframes:

`df1`

```
A B C
1 1 1
2 2 2
```

`df2`

```
A B C
3 3 3
4 4 4
```

`df3`

```
A B
5 5
```

So I want to concat all dataframes to become the following one:

```
A B C
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 NaN
```

I tried with `pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])` with both `axis=0` and `axis=1` but none of them works as expected.

Comment: What is the output you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are same common columns names , working nice - common columns are aligned properly:

```
print (df1.columns.tolist())
['A', 'B', 'C']
print (df2.columns.tolist())
['A', 'B', 'C']
print (df3.columns.tolist())
['A', 'B']
```

If possible som trailing whitespaces, is possible use [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
print (df1.columns.tolist())
['A', 'B ', 'C']

df1.columns = df1.columns.str.strip()

print (df1.columns.tolist())
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Also parameter `ignore_index=True` is for default RangeIndex after `concat`, for avoid duplicated index and add parameter `sort` for avoid `FutureWarning`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], ignore_index=True, sort=True)
print (df)
   A  B    C
0  1  1  1.0
1  2  2  2.0
2  3  3  3.0
3  4  4  4.0
4  5  5  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], ignore_index=True)

df.fillna("NA", inplace=True)
```

Comment: In my opinion it is not good idea `df.fillna("NA", inplace=True)`, because get mixed values - numeric with strings and some pandas function failed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to tell `concat` to ignore the `index`:

```py
result = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], ignore_index=True)
```